# Apache Cordova (cordova-android) got error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

i'm trying to build a Android app with Apache Cordova, i got an error:

```
Application Error
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:8080/index.html)
```

[View image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ukqm.png)

Now I don't know what to do...

My config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.blabla" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <!-- metadata ...... !-->
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon src="icons/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="icons/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="icons/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="icons/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="icons/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

My plugins

```
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova-android-support-gradle-release
cordova-plugin-crypt-file-android
```

Apache Cordova v11.0.0

Thanks so much!

Comment: I am getting the same issue

Comment: Try clearing your cache for cordova build output. That's the ONLY thing that worked for me -- a fresh clean build. I tried downgrading android target api level, tried usesCleartextTraffic, tried access allow whitelisting everything with wildcards, tried removing all cordova plugins ... nothing worked. But then I manually deleted the build output and build it from scratch and error went away.  I have no idea. Fluke??

Comment: im stuck with this. deleting build folder doesnt work either. im running cordova 12. agp 8.2, gradle 8.5